# Free Shipping in particular products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, shopping-cart-price-rules, shipping-methods, free-shipping

How can set the rule in particular products in particular quantity purchase two packets it will have free shipping

for example: gold cup- every single purchase of 2 packets (500 gms each) will have free shipping

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use *Promotions -> Shopping Cart Rules*

In the condition tab set this condition

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching
ALL  of these conditions: 
    SKU  is  YOUR SKU
```

And then set Free Shipping under Actions to yes

Or in pictures:

[image: Step one]

[image]

Comment: sorry i can't find the SKU

Comment: http://kaybs.in/image/1.png

please open the  link

Comment: Go into catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes and check for sku and check if it says "Use for Price Rule Conditions --> Yes"

Comment: yes, i got it, but is it not a text field shows dropdown 
http://kaybs.in/image/1.png